# Streaming a WebPage to YouTube using FFMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, phantomjs, video-streaming, streaming

I'm trying to stream a webpage to `YouTube` using `phantomjs` and `ffmpeg`.
Long question short:

**This works**. The video is saved to [test.flv](https://pedrolobito.com/stackoverflow/test.flv):

```
phantomjs runner.js|ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -r 10 -s 1280x720 -i - -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 10 -g 20 -vb 400k -maxrate 400k -minrate 400k -bufsize 800k -threads 6 -q:v 0 -t 10 -f flv test.flv
```

**This doesn't**. Despite no errors, nothing is streamed to `YouTube`.

```
phantomjs runner.js|ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 10 -s 1280x720 -i - -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 10 -g 2 -vb 400k -maxrate 400k -minrate 400k -bufsize 800k -threads 6 -q:v 0 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxx
```

---

**Remarks**:

1. I'm aware `phantomjs` isn't actively developed anymore, but this doesn't seem
   relevant since the `phantomjs` script works as intended;
2. `phantomjs` script: [runner.js](https://pedrolobito.com/stackoverflow/runner.js);
3. I've tried different `ffmpeg` settings, like `frame-rates`, `bit-rates` and `bufsize` to no avail.
4. Both commands are similar, but the 1st outputs to local-file [`test.flv`](https://pedrolobito.com/stackoverflow/test.flv) while 2nd to `YouTube`;
5. I've used the `YouTube` streaming key on OBS Studio and it works normally;
6. `ffmpeg` output while *streaming* to `YouTube`:

`frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=42.0 size=      94kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate=1531.0kbits/                                                                   frame=   18 fps= 16 q=40.0 size=     130kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=1063.6kbits/                                                                   frame=   23 fps= 14 q=44.0 size=     149kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate= 810.8kbits/`

7. `ffmpeg version 4.2.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers` running on `Ubuntu-1804`

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the actual text. Pictures are not indexable by google, and some people have poor eye site, and use tools that can read the text, or change the font.

Comment: @szatmary For some reason, I wasn't  able to copy the  ffmpeg `stdout` before, that's why I posted the photo. I updated the question with the actual text, thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an audio stream. It can be from a file, or you can generate silent/dummy audio stream using the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

```
phantomjs runner.js | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 10 -video_size 1280x720 -re -i - -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -g 20 -b:v 400k -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Unrelated changes:

- Use the image2pipe input options instead of generics. See `ffmpeg -h demuxer=image2pipe`
- Removed `-deinterlace`. I doubt the input is interlaced. If it is use a filter instead (`-deinterlace` uses the [yadif filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif), but is less customizable than directly using yadif).
- You don't need to add the `-r` output option if the input `-framerate` option is the same value, so it has been removed from your command.
- Let the encoder automatically choose the optimal number of threads by omitting the `-threads` option.
- `-q:v 0` is ignored by libx264. Remove it.
- `-g` can be set to *frame rate x 2*.
- You can use `ffmpeg` to capture the screen if you don't want to use additional javascripts.

Comment: Hi @llogan, unfortunately the problem still persist using your code, nothing is streamed. I don't think I can use ffmpeg to capture the screen because I'm running it on a headless server. Did you test the cmd line? If so, did it work?

Comment: @PedroLobito I forgot `-re` and an `-i`. Try updated answer.